# Where are Palos Hills and San Pedro?

Tags: plot-explanation, awkward

In [Awkward](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663676/?ref_=ttep_ep_tt), the main location is the Palos Hills High School. Is this **Palos Hills, Illinois**, near Chicago?

In the double episode *Snow Job* (season 4), the town name **San Pedro** (or Saint Pedro?) is mentioned. It is the place where Eva grew up, actually her grandmother's place. Is it in **California**, to the South of Los Angeles? Or is there a town or maybe just a district called that name nearby the main location Palos Hills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the first one because I lived very close to it.  Yes, there is a Palos Hills near Chicago, it is a suburb on the southwest side.  There is no "Palos Hills High School" as far as I know though, the only high school in Palos Hills is Stagg.  Which makes sense since I doubt the show could use a real high school's name.

[Palos Hills Map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Palos+Hills,+IL+60465/@41.6713795,-87.8661065,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x880e38f7775f1d2b:0x7b83f02270e560fd!8m2!3d41.6966992!4d-87.8169984)

I can answer the second as well, because Google exists.  There is a San Pedro in the Los Angeles area of California.  In fact it looks to be within the city of Los Angeles itself.  I certainly do not know of any San Pedro around Palos Hills / Chicago, and I know most of the cities around here.  In fact "San" as part of a city name is not a Chicago thing at all, it's a California thing based on Spanish ministries, so it is safe to say that they are not referring to anything in the Chicago area with this one.

[San Pedro Map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/San+Pedro,+Los+Angeles,+CA/@33.4192483,-118.7703276,9z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x80dd35ae16ed8aa5:0x4147d57f086875f!8m2!3d33.7360619!4d-118.2922461)

Comment: Maybe their San Pedro is a made-up border district of Chicaco, or Palos Hills is a factious area in California... In season 5 ep. 20, the sentence "either [marry a rich guy] or move to San Pedro" fell and it seems unlikely that one would move across the US because you can't afford your upper-class accommodation anymore. There are various indications in the series that Palos Hills is situated closer to the East Coast than the West Coast, so I guess San Pedro is supposed to be a Chicago poor quarter.

Comment: I guess that is possible but it'd be a poor researcher who decided to name an area in Chicago "San" something.  Nothing around here is named that way.

Comment: Meanwhile I remembered that a town Reseda was mentioned in the first season (~1h by car away from Palos Hills), and that happens to exist in the LA outskirts. So I believe the series is situated on the West coast after all.

Answer (score 2):

It’s Palos Verdes Estates, CA. Based on Palos Verdes High School (I went to school there). San Pedro is about 20 minutes away from PV and is considered “sketchy” by PV people, like in the show.

Comment: Cool! Looks like it wasn't filmed there however. The stands are much shorter in Palos Verdes and there are no buildings behind the sports field that look like the ones from the series: https://goo.gl/maps/6Z4o88Fq79aTc28U9 vs https://youtu.be/Mv1BG3Nlm2U?t=0